# Nodejs Mogoose bulkWrite with condition check before upsert, and missing default fields

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**Problem**: How to bulk insert million records by making condition check on a filed

**Situation**: I have to run a standalone node script multiple times and will get JSON data that needs to be inserted to Mongo DB. This JSON data can have same data which is inserted earlier or can have a change in one field (count) that needs to be updated.

Field 'count' can be greater, equal or lesser than the existing entry.

**Requirement** : I need to update that document (row) **only if the count is greater** than existing one.

I should be able to do this by fetching the existing records and then looping every record and do condition check. This is not I'm looking for as there will be millions of records to insert.

**Question 1**. Is there a way in mongoose `bulkWrite` to have such condition check before `upsert`?

**Question 2**. If `bulkWrite` is not what I should be using what
    is the alternate solution which has better performance and less
    overhead on application memory?

**MongoDB server Version**: 3.4.10

Below sample code inserts 2 records and after some delay, it tries to insert another record with only **change in count** that is lesser than existing entry in DB.

At this situation, my requirement is not to update the second record count value.

**Question 3:** Why is the default value fields are not set in DB?

**Question 4:** When dealing with huge set of data, is there an event to know if all the records are written to disk? As the DB Save is '`async`' call, when to trigger `database.close` and `process.exit()`, current code is simply waiting for 5 seconds which is wrong way to implement.

If I don't close DB, application wont exit, and if I exit application with some timeout, it might result in exiting code before full data is written to disk.

```
/**
* Get DB Connection
*/

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/sample";
let DATABASE = {};

DATABASE.connect = () => {
    let db = mongoose.createConnection(url, { autoIndex: false, connectTimeoutMS: 30000, reconnectTries: 30, reconnectInterval: 2000 });
    console.log("Database connecting to URL ", url);

    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    return db;
}

DATABASE.close = (db) => {
    if (db) {
        db.close(function () {
            console.log('Mongoose default connection with DB disconnected ');
        });
    }
}

/**
* Now define schema (will be part of module file)
*/

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var apiDetailSchema = new Schema({
    ip: String,
    instance: Number,
    component: String,
    logDate: Number,
    count: Number,
    apiMethod: {type:String, default:'DEFAULT METHOD', required: true},
    api: String,
    status: String,
    httpMethod: String,
    environment: String,
    datacenter: {type:String, default:'INDIA', required:true},
});

apiDetailSchema.index({ ip: 1, instance: 1, component: 1, logDate: 1, api: 1, status: 1, httpMethod:1, environment:1, datacenter:1}, { unique: true });

const API_DETAIL = {};

API_DETAIL.connect = () => {
    if (API_DETAIL.db) {
        console.log("Returning existing DB for API Schema");
        return API_DETAIL.db;
    }
    console.log("Requesting New DB connection for API Schema");

    API_DETAIL.db = DATABASE.connect();
    return API_DETAIL.db;
}

API_DETAIL.close = () => {
    if (API_DETAIL.db) DATABASE.close(API_DETAIL.db);
}
API_DETAIL.connect();

API_DETAIL.SCHEMA = API_DETAIL.db.model('apiDetail', apiDetailSchema);

/**
* Use of API_DETAIL to insert data
*/
var bulkUpdateApiData = (data) => {
    let total = data.length;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (total === 0) {
            resolve("NO DATA to update API details");

        }
        console.log("Bulkupdating "+total+" API records");
        let db = API_DETAIL.connect(); // Connect to DB
        if (!db) {
            console.log("Failed to obtain DB connection during API Bulk update");
            reject("ERROR: DB Connection failed");
        }
        let bulkOps = [];

        console.log("Going to Bulk update "+total+" API details");

        data.forEach(d => {
            let { ip, instance, component, logDate, count, api, status, httpMethod, environment, datacenter } = d;
            let upsertDoc = {
                'updateOne': {
                    // Filter applied to all field except count, so that it will update count
                    // TODO: Check if the count is more, then only update
                    'filter': { ip, instance, component, logDate, api, status, httpMethod, environment, datacenter },
                    'update': d,
                    'upsert': true
                }
            }
            bulkOps.push(upsertDoc);
        });
        API_DETAIL.SCHEMA.bulkWrite(bulkOps).then(BulkWriteOpResultObject => {
            console.log(total + " API Details updated to DB");
            // console.log(JSON.stringify(BulkWriteOpResultObject, null, 2));
            resolve("Updated "+total+ " API Details");
        }).catch(e => {
            console.log("ERROR upserting addIpDetail", e);
            reject(e);
        });
    });
} // Function : bulkUpdateApiData

let initialData = [
    {
        "ip": "192.168.1.2",
        "instance": 2,
        "component": "NODE",
        "logDate": "20180114",
        "api": "/services/srest/abc/authenticator/login",
        "status": "200",
        "httpMethod": "POST", 
        "environment": "production",
        "count": 8
    },
    {
        "ip": "192.168.1.2",
        "instance": 2,
        "component": "NODE",
        "logDate": "20180114",
        "api": "/services/srest/abc/authenticator/logout",
        "status": "204",
        "httpMethod": "POST", 
        "environment": "production",
        "count": 8888 // Initially it was more
    }];


bulkUpdateApiData(initialData).then(output => {
    console.log(output);
}).catch(e => {
    console.log("Something went wrong during API Detail bulk update", e);
});


let newData = [
    {
        "ip": "192.168.1.2",
        "instance": 2,
        "component": "NODE",
        "logDate": "20180114",
        "api": "/services/srest/abc/authenticator/logout",
        "status": "204",
        "httpMethod": "POST", 
        "environment": "production",
        "count": 10 // Now it is lesser than initial one
    }];

// Wait for 2 seconds to complete previous write operation, 
// if not below bulkWrite will complete first !!!

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("=================================================");
    console.log("Bulk updating EXISTING data with lesser count");
    bulkUpdateApiData(newData).then(output => {
        console.log(output);
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log("Something went wrong during API Detail bulk update", e);
    });
}, 2000);
console.log("-----------------------------------------------");

// As DB write / save is async operation, When should I call this CLOSE connection? 
// Is there a way to know when exactly DB write is completed?
setTimeout(API_DETAIL.close, 5000);
```

**Output:**

```
> node bulkWrite.js

Requesting New DB connection for API Schema
Database connecting to URL  mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/sample
Bulkupdating 2 API records
Returning existing DB for API Schema
Going to Bulk update 2 API details
-----------------------------------------------
2 API Details updated to DB
Updated 2 API Details
=================================================
Bulk updating EXISTING data with lesser count
Bulkupdating 1 API records
Returning existing DB for API Schema
Going to Bulk update 1 API details
1 API Details updated to DB
Updated 1 API Details
Mongoose default connection with DB disconnected
```

**DB Output**, where the second record / document has update value in filed 'count'

```
> db.apidetails.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a5df2d1952021f65578fc8f"),
        "api" : "/services/srest/abc/authenticator/login",
        "component" : "NODE",
        "count" : 8,
        "datacenter" : null,
        "environment" : "production",
        "httpMethod" : "POST",
        "instance" : 2,
        "ip" : "192.168.1.2",
        "logDate" : 20180114,
        "status" : "200"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a5df2d1952021f65578fc90"),
        "api" : "/services/srest/abc/authenticator/logout",
        "component" : "NODE",
        "count" : 10,
        "datacenter" : null,
        "environment" : "production",
        "httpMethod" : "POST",
        "instance" : 2,
        "ip" : "192.168.1.2",
        "logDate" : 20180114,
        "status" : "204"
}
```

Comment: 4) the callback is called when mongodb stored the data. Then you can shutdown it.

Comment: Even though the actual writing is happening behind the scene, callback is called (promise). That is causing issue when there is huge data to be written.